# How to check if JavaScript file is yet to loaded or loading

Tags: javascript, selenium, web, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I am doing GUI automation of my website via Selenium (RobotFramework). The problem I am facing is:

When my automation script clicks on some element (button,link etc) which is supposed to perform some action, it dose nothing. This happening randomly. When we test is manually, it works all the time. One observation is, with slower machine/environment, this tends to happen more.

I suspect this is happening either due to some corresponding JS is not loaded yet or if there is any such thing called "action binding" with each elemetnt, has not happened.

Some question
- Is there a way to find out if all the JS calls are over?
- In case action binding happens, has it already bound or not.

Please share if you have any other solution.

Comment: For non-production uses (debugging), you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time

Comment: Thank you @Bloc97. I am looking for something that does not need any modification in JS code. Something which can tell me if JS is loaded or not.

Answer (score 1):

do you know what is last to load on the page?  This should be very easy to find out via Developer Tools in your browser of choice.

You can then easily use a Wait Until Keyword (there are many variations) to wait until that last item appears as you expect, then continue with your test.  Setting the timeout length and interval will help control the overhead of time/performance.

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible   id=finalElement    10    finalElement did not appear on the screen before timeout period
```

http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html - please see the documentation for further examples and options in terms of keywords